# htmlwidget tag should be htmlwidgets

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The [htmlwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidget) tag should be [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) since `htmlwidgets` is technically the proper name of the R package. See the following links for reference:

https://www.htmlwidgets.org

https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets

https://cran.r-project.org/package=htmlwidgets

---

For clarification, the [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) tag does **not** currently exist, and when I try to add/create it by tagging a question with it, an error is shown that says...

"You are attempting to create the tag [htmlwidgets]; however the tag [htmlwidget] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta"...

hence my post/question here.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) is better than [htmlwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidget). However, at the moment [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) isn't used for any question. Consequently, you can't propose [htmlwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidget) to become a synonym for [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets). Based on [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/256214) there several courses of action you could consider:

1. Re-tag all [htmlwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidget) questions to [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets). As there are only 191 question, this isn't too much work.
2. Just re-tag just several questions to [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) and propose [htmlwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidget) as a synonym to [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) (make sure you re-tag question such that you will be to propose a tag-synonym & other people are elegible to on that proposal). After that people can vote.
3. Based on this thread, a moderator could step in and assign the tag synonym immediatly (i.e. bulk rename the tag; by far the easiest option in my opinion).

EDIT: As @CJYetman said in a comment below, options 1 & 2 aren't possible because you will get an error saying **"You are attempting to create the tag [htmlwidgets]; however the tag [htmlwidget] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta"** leaving only option 3 as an alternative.

Comment: I would really opt for 3 but there is one down vote on the question. If it stays that way in the next 6 to 8 days I wouldn't worry too much but if it gets more downvotes something might be off.

Comment: I was not able to re-tag questions with [htmlwidgets] because that tag does not already exist, and stackoverflow gives an error saying "You are attempting to create the tag [htmlwidgets]; however the tag [htmlwidget] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta"... hence my post/question here. So option 3 seems to be the only viable option.

Comment: Option 4. Get a moderator to rename the tag using the bulk tag tool, which doesn't bump any questions.

Comment: Option 4 as recommended by @TinyGiant is really the right choice here, and in almost all similar cases.  Any retagging and synomizing effort seems like an excessive amount of work unless there are only a few questions with the tag

Comment: I like Option 4 more...

Comment: @TinyGiant Isn't that the same as option 3? (at least that's what I meant)

Comment: Oh, then I like Option 3.

Comment: @BhargavRao edited accordingly :-)

Comment: @BhargavRao, does it make sense to immediately add `[htmlwidget]` as synonym, to avoid future mishaps?

Comment: @Luuklag usually we don't create synonyms for renames. Also non diamond users can't create a tag with a non plural form of a present tag, so there's no need to be worried :)

Comment: @CJYetman I wasn't aware of that. Will edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score -3):

I think that both [htmlwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidget) and its plural form are very bad and misleading tags. This tag is meant to represent an R package (according to it's Wiki), but to a normal SO user it sounds like it is meant to represent a combo of [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widget) tags. And since there are much more non-R users than R users it seems to me that it is likely to create more confusion than value. I think that in *this specific case*, both of these tags should be blacklisted (so they won't be recreated again) and perhaps (if we really want to), we could create some more specific tag (although I'm aware this is not the general guideline) such as [r-htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-htmlwidgets) or such.

The only thing I'm worried about, if an R user will add [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widget) to his/her question and would create confusion the other way around. Though I have a feeling that an [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) expert could also help on a question like that even without knowing R. Maybe, that way, much more people could help the OP as practically none really watches [htmlwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets) anyway.

There are examples for that already in R, such as the [r-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-markdown) tag, for example (though maybe in this case just tagging with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) would be better option).

Comment: There are currently [3 questions tagged \[htmlwidgets\] excluding any r / shiny / d3 /r-markdown related tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlwidgets+-r+-d3.js+-shiny+-networkd3+-r-markdown), all of which still look to be r related. So...I mean, if it was being misused then maybe, but that does not seem to be the case... at all